# PHP Upload image into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with adding image into database, it's insert all fill just image get error and it's not added image.
Here is code:

```
<?php 
include '../dbc.php'; 

$message='';
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $descr = $_POST["descr"];
  $price = $_POST["price"];
  $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
  $item_number = $_POST["item_number"];
  $cat = $_POST["cat"];
  $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 


 if((!$name) || (!$desc) || (!$price) || (!$quantity) || (!$item_number) || 
    (!$cat) || (!$image)){
    $message = "Fill all inputs!";
  }
  $name_query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM products WHERE name='$name' 
                      LIMIT 1") or die("Can't check name!");
      $count_name = mysql_num_rows($name_query);

  if($count_name > 0){
        $message = "This product exist!";
  }else{
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

        $query= mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name, description, 
                price,quantity, item_number, category, image) VALUES 
                ('$name', '$descr', '$price', '$quantity', '$item_number',
                '$cat', '$image')") or die("Can't addi");
        $message="Product is added!"; 
    }
} 

?>
```

Theres error: Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: have you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  in your form??

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used. Also `addslashes` is not suitable to escape data that needs to go into the database. And thirdly you should consider using the file system to save files and just store the file name in the database.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to add the image into the database, it's better to upload the image into the "disk" and save the reference ("/images/folder/image.jpg") into the database.

http://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php

Comment: for images less than 5KB can be easily manipulate with db. for more protection.

Comment: @ReNiShAR Images can just as easily be stored off the document root and have a script file access the image.

Comment: k thanks... i know.. me also used it through out my works,,,,